# Why does an error pop up in the IDLE Shell, but my program seems to run fine?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a timer that lets you input the amount of time you want to make it count down for in minutes, so if you entered 5 minutes, it would count down until it reaches zero. I've also added a "Reset Timer" button. The button seems to work fine, and as intended, but an error pops up in the shell.

**This is My Code:**

```py
#Imports and Functions
import tkinter as tk
import time

TimeDestroyed = "No"

def Destroy():
    TimeDestroyed = "Yes"
    
    Time.destroy()
    ResetTimer.destroy()

    TimeReset()

def TimeReset():
    global Instructions, TimeInputter, ConfirmTime
    
    Instructions = tk.Label(
        ClockFrame,
        text="Enter how long you will be working for (In Minutes):",
        font=40
        )
    Instructions.pack(pady=10)


    TimeInputter = tk.Entry(
        ClockFrame,
        width=40,
        font=40
        )
    TimeInputter.pack(side=tk.LEFT)


    ConfirmTime = tk.Button(
        ClockFrame,
        text="Confirm Time",
        command=TimeSet
        )
    ConfirmTime.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)


def TimeSet():
    global Time, ResetTimer
    
    InputtedTime = int(TimeInputter.get()) * 60

    Instructions.destroy()
    TimeInputter.destroy()
    ConfirmTime.destroy()

    Time = tk.Label(
        ClockFrame,
        text="",
        font=('Arial', 70)
        )
    Time.pack()

    ResetTimer = tk.Button(
    ClockFrame,
    text="Reset Timer",
    command=Destroy
    )
    ResetTimer.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
    
    for x in range(InputtedTime, 0, -1):
        window.update()
        seconds = x % 60
        minutes = int(x / 60) % 60
        hours = int(x / 3600)
        
        if TimeDestroyed == "No":
            Time.config(text=f"{hours:02}:{minutes:02}:{seconds:02}")
            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            break
        
    if TimeDestroyed == "No":    
        Time.destroy()
    else:
        pass

    TimeReset()

    

#Task Functions
def TaskSet():
    global Task
    
    def Check():
        if cbvar.get():
            Task.destroy()
            TaskReset()
        else:
            pass

    #Needed Variables for Checkbox
    cbvar = tk.IntVar()
    InputtedTask = InputTask.get()

    #Removing Previous Inputs
    TaskFrame.destroy()
    InputTask.destroy()
    ConfirmTask.destroy()

    #Creating the Checkbox
    Task = tk.Checkbutton(
        window,
        text="Task: " + InputtedTask,
        font=('Arial', 20),
        variable = cbvar,
        command=Check)

    Task.pack()

def TaskReset():
    global TaskFrame, InputTask, ConfirmTask
    
    TaskFrame = tk.Frame(window)
    TaskFrame.pack()

    InputTask = tk.Entry(TaskFrame, width=40, font=40)
    InputTask.pack(pady=10, side=tk.LEFT)

    ConfirmTask = tk.Button(TaskFrame, text="Confirm Task", command=TaskSet)
    ConfirmTask.pack(pady=10, side=tk.RIGHT)

#Creates a Window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Focus-o-Clock!")

#Clock

ClockFrame = tk.Frame(window, bg="#CDCDC5")
ClockFrame.pack()



#Functions
TaskReset()
TimeReset()

window.mainloop()
```

After you enter the amount of time, you then get the option to reset the timer. If you reset it, the timer gets deleted and the prompt to enter the amount of time comes up again, but this error pops up:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File...\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File..., line 104, in TimeSet
    Time.config(text=f"{hours:02}:{minutes:02}:{seconds:02}")
  File...\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File...\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1692, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!frame.!label2"
```

Now typically I wouldn't worry about this since the program works fine, but it's for a school project and I might get deductions for having an error pop up in the shell. If anyone can help solve it, I would gladly appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please be careful not to change quoting / syntax highlighting when you cut content down for publication. The text colors changing in your stack trace (because you cut out the opening quotes that start filenames) are very distracting when trying to read it.

Comment: That said, does your professor grade in IDLE? If they don't use it to grade, and the problem doesn't happen outside IDLE at all, I'd completely ignore it as an IDLE bug. (IDLE itself uses tkinter, so running a tkinter program _from IDLE_ -- unless spawning off a subprocess -- has potential for things to be odd in a way that's very IDLE-specific).

Comment: BTW, as a completely separate matter, I'd urge you to try to redesign your program to get rid of all the `global`s and instead make your functions methods on an object that carries all the shared state. Not part of the problem you came here to ask about, but if I were grading it's something I'd mark down for.

Comment: See [ask]. Do a preliminary debugging. Anyway, the error clearly says you called ```Time.config()``` for an invalid(destroyed) widget. Did you check the ```TimeDestroyed``` is valid? You forget the ```global``` statement on it.